# DIscord.js code works on windows and not ubuntu linux

Tags: javascript, typescript, ubuntu, discord.js, runtime-error

So I have a discord.js program... it runs fine on Windows... on Ubuntu it only registers the commands and goes online... never replies to commands or interactions...

Here's my code:

```
//Client.ts
export class ExtendedClient extends Client {
    commands: Collection<string, CommandType> = new Collection();

    constructor() {
        super({ intents: 32767 });
    }

    start(){
        this.RegisterModules()
        this.login(process.env.BotToken)
    }

    async ImportFile(FilePath: string){
        return (await import(FilePath))?.default;
    }

    async RegisterCommands( {Commands, GuildId: GuildID}: RegisterCommandOptions){
        if (GuildID){
            this.guilds.cache.get(GuildID)?.commands.set(Commands);
            console.log(`Registered ${Commands.length} commands in guild ${GuildID}`);
            
        }else{
            this.application?.commands.set(Commands);
            console.log(`Registered ${Commands.length} global commands`);
        }
    }


    async RegisterModules(){
        // Commands
        const slashCommands: ApplicationCommandDataResolvable[] = [];
        const commandFiles = await globPromise(
            `${__dirname}/../Commands/*/*{.ts,.js}`
        );
        commandFiles.forEach(async (filePath) => {
            const command: CommandType = await this.ImportFile(filePath);
            if (!command.name) return;
            console.log(command);

            this.commands.set(command.name, command);
            slashCommands.push(command);
        });

        this.on("ready", () => {
            this.RegisterCommands({
                Commands: slashCommands,
                GuildId: process.env.GuildId
            });
            server.CheckSentInvoices()
        });

        // Events
        const EventFiles = await globPromise(
            `${__dirname}/../events/*{.ts,.js}`
        );
        EventFiles.forEach(async (filePath) => {
            const event: Event<keyof ClientEvents> = await this.ImportFile(
                filePath
            );
            this.on(event.event, event.run);
        });
    }
}
```

```
//ready.ts
import { Event } from "../structures/Event";

export default new Event('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Bot is alive!`);
});
```

this is the console.log() I'm waiting for... I get it on windows and after it the bot is fine and running well... but on Ubuntu it never works

Comment: Make sure you **don't** copy over your `node_modules` folder to the ubuntu system. This folder contains platform-specific packages that may or may not work on other systems. I'd recommend deleting this folder on your ubuntu system and re-running `npm install`.

Comment: did that with no luck